# Wrong URL when loading files in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

When I try to load the website on localhost, I get the following URL,

```
http://localhost/beta/localhostskin/frontend/default/default/css/styles.css
```

The localhost is getting repeated. Here is my config

```
 5 | default |        0 | web/unsecure/base_url       | localhost                   |
|         6 | default |        0 | web/secure/base_url         | localhost                   |
|        15 | default |        0 | web/unsecure/base_link_url  | {{unsecure_base_url}}       |
|        16 | default |        0 | web/unsecure/base_skin_url  | {{unsecure_base_url}}skin/  |
|        17 | default |        0 | web/unsecure/base_media_url | {{unsecure_base_url}}media/ |
|        18 | default |        0 | web/unsecure/base_js_url    | {{unsecure_base_url}}js/    |
|        19 | default |        0 | web/secure/base_link_url    | {{secure_base_url}}         |
|        20 | default |        0 | web/secure/base_skin_url    | {{secure_base_url}}skin/    |
|        21 | default |        0 | web/secure/base_media_url   | {{secure_base_url}}media/   |
|        22 | default |        0 | web/secure/base_js_url      | {{secure_base_url}}js/
```

And for merging

```
 571 | default |        0 | dev/js/merge_files      | 0     |
|       572 | default |        0 | dev/css/merge_css_files | 0
```

Can anyone tell me, how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

I think,

> http://localhost/beta/

is your base url. So just give it as such for base url and secure base url. Leave all other url fields empty and save. Clear all the cache and reload the site.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that web/secure/base_url ends with a slash (/). It looks like in your case base_url should be "http://localhost/beta/localhost/"